# Which definition of "valuable" is used in "Black pepper was as valuable as gold"?

Tags: meaning

Which definition of the word 'valuable' is right in this sentence?

> Black pepper was as valuable as gold at that time.

1. having considerable monetary worth
2. having qualities worthy of respect, admiration, or esteem
3. of considerable use, service, or importance

I think it's number 1 but I want to be confirmed.

Comment: Yes I agree, the first definition fits best.

Comment: It could also be 3 if it has an intrinsic use; eg for preserving food (like salt), or curing ailments (like certain herbs). But the first one is probably most likely given the absence of any further context.

Comment: @OliverMason it means with cash value, as gold was the default currency. so Number 1 is the only option. Of course it was because of number 3 that number 1 was true.

Comment: In general, you'd have to understand the context to tell.  But at one time pepper was quite valuable, as it had to be imported by camel from the Orient.

Answer (score 2):

> Black pepper was as valuable as gold at that time.

valuable in this sense is talking about monetary worth.

[was-pepper-once-worth-its-weight-in-gold?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19998/was-pepper-once-worth-its-weight-in-gold.)

But of course pepper was only that valuable because of its newness, its rarity, the dangers of shipping it back to Europe, but also it's incredible usefulness in cooking, in adding new flavours to the old foods people had been eating for generations.

Comment: As I see it, "black pepper was as valuable as gold at that time", meaning it had "considerable monetary worth".  Why?  Because it had culinary and other "qualities worthy of respect, admiration, or esteem"--it tasted good--and had "considerable use, service, or importance" in the preparation and preservation of food.  So all three reasons--in the order they were given in the OP--apply here.

Comment: Yes but two and three are because answers, it was as valuable as gold because...